# Group by counting various types

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have articles that can be commented by either user or staff:

```
create table article (id int, title varchar(30));
create table type (id int, name varchar(30));
create table comment (id int, content varchar(30), article_id int, type_id int);
insert into article (id, title) values (1, 'article1'), (2, 'article2'), (3, 'article3'), (4, 'article4');
insert into type (id, name) values (1, 'User comment'), (2, 'Staff comment');
insert into comment (id, content, article_id, type_id) values (1, 'comment1', 1, 1), (2, 'comment2', 1, 2), (3, 'comment3', 2, 1), (4, 'comment4', 3, 2);
```

I can then count the number of each comment type:

```
select a.id, a.title,
case when c.type_id = 1 then count(a.id) else 0 end as usercommentcount,
case when c.type_id = 2 then count(a.id) else 0 end as staffcommentcount
from article a left join comment c on a.id = c.article_id
group by a.id, c.type_id;

id title    usercommentcount staffcommentcount
1  article1 1                0
1  article1 0                1
2  article2 1                0
3  article3 0                1
4  article4 0                0
```

However, since I'm using Doctrine, I want to group by article.id only, but this counts article1 as having 2 user comments and 0 staff comment:

```
select a.id, a.title,
case when c.type_id = 1 then count(a.id) else 0 end as usercommentcount,
case when c.type_id = 2 then count(a.id) else 0 end as staffcommentcount
from article a left join comment c on a.id = c.article_id
group by a.id;

id title    usercommentcount staffcommentcount
1  article1 2                0
2  article2 1                0
3  article3 0                1
4  article4 0                0
```

Is there a way to fix this that would work with Doctrine QueryBuilder, i.e. not using rollups etc.? Ideally, I want a result like this:

```
id title    usercommentcount staffcommentcount
1  article1 1                1
2  article2 1                0
3  article3 0                1
4  article4 0                0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sum(case ... end) does the job here:

```
select a.id, a.title,
sum(case when c.type_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as usercommentcount,
sum(case when c.type_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as staffcommentcount
from article a
left join comment c on a.id = c.article_id
group by a.id;
```

Comment: Sum(c.type_id = 1) is synonymous